# scroll back to the top of a box on mouseout

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

Please, run this snippet to better understand my issue

```css
body{
  background-color: #E13241;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#wrapper{
  width: 1130px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4{
  width: 230px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-spacing: -1px;  
  margin-left: 15px; /* or 0px */
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.2);
  padding: 15px;
 
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

h3{
  text-align: center;
}

.box1:hover, .box2:hover, .box3:hover, .box4:hover{
  width: 230px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px;} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.2);}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.2);}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">
    <h3>
      Title Box 1
    </h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, beatae! Sed assumenda cupiditate quasi officiis laborum, minima at error tempore. Voluptatibus facere iste qui? Fugit non perferendis, accusamus nostrum deleniti? 
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus consequuntur laborum porro nemo, quisquam minus minima eius, deserunt similique, laboriosam dolorum tenetur et repudiandae rem fugit illum perspiciatis nam totam.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <h3>
      Title Box 2
    </h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, beatae! Sed assumenda cupiditate quasi officiis laborum, minima at error tempore. Voluptatibus facere iste qui? Fugit non perferendis, accusamus nostrum deleniti? 
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus consequuntur laborum porro nemo, quisquam minus minima eius, deserunt similique, laboriosam dolorum tenetur et repudiandae rem fugit illum perspiciatis nam totam.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    <h3>
      Title Box 3
    </h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, beatae! Sed assumenda cupiditate quasi officiis laborum, minima at error tempore. Voluptatibus facere iste qui? Fugit non perferendis, accusamus nostrum deleniti? 
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus consequuntur laborum porro nemo, quisquam minus minima eius, deserunt similique, laboriosam dolorum tenetur et repudiandae rem fugit illum perspiciatis nam totam.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <h3>
      Title Box 4
    </h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, beatae! Sed assumenda cupiditate quasi officiis laborum, minima at error tempore. Voluptatibus facere iste qui? Fugit non perferendis, accusamus nostrum deleniti? 
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus consequuntur laborum porro nemo, quisquam minus minima eius, deserunt similique, laboriosam dolorum tenetur et repudiandae rem fugit illum perspiciatis nam totam.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I have a box within a div. When I hover it, the box gets higher and it is possible to scroll inside the box. But I can't figure a way to automatically scroll back to the top of the box when I do not hover the box anymore.

I've tried multiple things, including this js code I found in another answer :

```
$('#box').show();
$('#box').scrollTop(0);
$('html,body, #box').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100);
```

But it's just cancelling all my css and do not work in this specific scenario.

Any idea or direction to follow ?

Comment: i tried document.querySelector(".box3").scrollTop = 0 works for reseting the scrollbar, so add it to an onmouseout event should work.

Comment: Hmm. I'm quite a newbie in js and I couldn't make it work with the code you shared. Did you actually type document.querySelector(".box3").scrollTop = 0 in the js panel ? It didn't work for me

Comment: I moved to box with 'Title Box 3', scrolled to the bottom, and I opened console and ran it there

Comment: I get it. It refreshed the pen when you insert your code in the console but you can type anywhere else (in the text for instance) and it will refresh too. I think the js code has nothing to do with it. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: not really, here's an example of what i was talking about https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XPVJdz

Comment: I see this is clever :) It is kinda buggy sometime though, I don't know why it's scrolling top for no reasons at time, but here's a good start thanks.

Comment: change onmouseout to onmouseleave should fix that

Comment: Great. This is it. Problem solved thank you.

Comment: @ChrisLi @Max Use `elem.onmouseleave` instead of `elem.onmouseout`, otherwise it also scrolls to top when moving the mouse *inside* the box. The `onmouseout` event propagates to all children, so each `p` element also receives the listener.

Comment: Also, @Max, the code snippet in your example is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), and you need to include the library for it to work, and then wrap the snippet in `$(document).ready(function() { ..your_code.. });`